# unable to update the title of angular 1 application on route change

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, title, directive

The following directive  is providing the current route value

```
(function () {
    var titleDirective=angular.module('titleDirective',[]);
    titleDirective.directive('testTitle',function ($rootScope, $timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            link: function() {
                var listener = function(event, toState) {
                    $timeout(function() {
                        $rootScope.title = (toState.data && toState.data.pageTitle)
                            ? toState.data.pageTitle
                            : 'Default title';
                    });
                };
                $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', listener);
            }
        };
    })
})();
```

and i have define the routes as shown below

```
 .state('admin.signIn', {
            url: '/signIn',
            templateUrl: 'credentials/signIn.html',
            controller: 'loginCtrl',
            data : { pageTitle: 'Home' }
        })
```

when i try to use the directive as shown below in index.html

```
<test-title>{{title}}</test-title>
```

but not sure how to update the value in the title tag of html on change the route

```
<title>Retailer Application</title>
```

not sure how to use the  {{title}} to behave like the title

Please suggest a way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your directive to :

```
myApp.directive('testTitle', function($rootScope, $timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: `<title>{{$root.title}}</title>`,
    link: function() {
      var listener = function(event, toState) {
        $timeout(function() {
          $rootScope.title = (toState.data && toState.data.pageTitle) ? toState.data.pageTitle : 'Default title';
        });
      };
      $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', listener);
    }
  };
});
```

Here as you're using $rootScope for title variable in template you've to use `{{$root.title}}`. After that just add `test-title` directive in head section of index.html

[**Working Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/utEy2akegKW2HFyaNIZh?p=preview)

Also make sure that you're using 0.4.2 version of ui-router. With recent version (1.x) of ui-router $stateChangeSuccess event is deprecated. Use `$transitions.onSuccess` instead.

[Official Documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki) & [issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/3458)

Comment: plunker example is amazing